# Flag weight gain by actions other than flagging?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, review, flag-weight

The Deputy tag on SO says:

> Achieved a flag weight of 500 by reviewing and flagging appropriately

Does that mean I can get flag weight by reviewing?

If so, how?

If not, is this a mistake in the badge's description?

Comment: I thought the exact same thing when I first used the review interface.

Comment: Step 1. Review.   Step 2. Flag if necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the definition of the Deputy badge has changed from the one quoted in this post, and this question asks about the outdated definition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think "reviewing and flagging appropriately" just means that reviewing is expected to *precede* flagging; it doesn't mean reviewing can by itself garner you flag weight.

For example:

> You'll get into a good college if you study and get good grades

No school will ever know whether you *actually* studied; they'll just see that you got good grades—but it's assumed that studying is a necessary antecedent to getting good grades.  It's similarly assumed that reviewing is a necessary antecedent to making appropriate flags.

You could theoretically flag random posts, get extremely lucky and score glorious flag weight, but more likely than not you'll have to review first.

Comment: Even if that is the case, the reviewing itself has no part in gaining the flag weight score. So I don't think it should appear in the description

Comment: @Truth - I think the point is that you're expected to review before flagging.  That's why it's worded that way.

Comment: Bah, this is getting a question fit for the english.stakcexchange.com :P I'll accept this answer, as it seems to be correct. But I still find it slightly off.

Comment: @Truth - the folks at English.SE would give you quite a detailed answer involving conjunctions, gerunds, etc etc -- ugh  :)

Comment: @AdamRackis Or we could just say, "Uh! Why don't you ask to the folks at Meta?" `:-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno - glad to hear you english.se folks have better things to do than parse SO badge texts :)